# showing -1 while getting the position of get_pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   ifstream fin;
    fin.open("pro.txt");
    char ch;
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
      fin.get(ch);
      cout<<ch;
    }
    fin.seekg(0);
    int pos=(int)fin.tellg();
    cout<<"\n pointer is at :"<<pos;
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

content of file pro.txt

```
this is the test file text
```

even after fin.seek(0) the position of get_pointer returned by fin.tellg() is always -1 (WHY ?). it happens only when i read the file till the eof(). HELP

output

```
this is the test file text
pointer is at: -1
```

Comment: Related: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the file at all? Make sure it is in the correct folder. If this is Visual Studio the default folder is the one containing the project file (unless you changed the debug settings for your project). Also you should update your code to warn the user if the file is not found.

Comment: thnx but it will be better if you copy my code and check youself,

Comment: i know how to read and write files

Comment: You forgot to [`clear()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) your streams failure state prior to seeking back to the beginning.

Comment: there is no problem in the file reading , file reading is correct the only wrong value is of fin.tellg

Comment: well you can make your own text file with same name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/):

> C++98: If the eofbit flag is set before the call, the function fails (sets failbit and returns).

If you do `fin.clear()` before seekg, it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Once your stream state hits failure (and it did) any stream operations, including seeking, will fail until that state is cleared.

Example (using string stream):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("Some text to read");
    char ch;
    while (iss.get(ch))
        std::cout << ch;
    std::cout << '\n';

    iss.clear(); // <<==== HERE
    iss.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    auto pos = iss.tellg();
    std::cout << "pos = " << pos << '\n';

    while (iss.get(ch))
        std::cout << ch;
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output**

```
Some text to read
pos = 0
Some text to read
```

Comment: which language is this  ?

Comment: @AkashKabir The code ? It's C++, compiled and tested using clang 3.8 in `-std=c++11` mode. Is it the `auto` that is throwing your compiler off ? if so, use `std::ios::pos_type pos = ...` instead. [See example here](http://ideone.com/oDKO3A).

Comment: what is isstringstream ? is it compiler specific?

Comment: No, its a string stream (as the example states), brought in by `<sstream>`. Read more about it [**here**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) (and bookmark that site, as it is the best online resource for C++ you're likely to find).